# How do I avoid using to many "I and My in first person narratives

Tags: narrative, viewpoint, grammatical-person

To give you a little context below.

"Yesterday, I was smiling, and tomorrow, I will try to hold my head up high.  But today, tears welled up in my eyes, as my worst fear looked me in the eyes as my life unfolded before me like a bad movie. It felt like a hurricane had slammed into my world and nothing seemed the same."

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you write your chapters as if you're writing a screenplay. You have to blend the best of third-person narration with the best of first-person narration. In that, you have to try to picture a movie screen and your characters on it, and just add little introspection throughout for that first-person effect. This is what I do and it works.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?  Thank you.